# recyclerview onBindViewHolder with getItemViewType white screens

Tags: android, android-viewholder, android-recyclerview

I'm using recyclerview with 5 different possible views. But when I try to bind any data to my views, it doesn't display at all.
If I don't bind any data and just display the different views, it displays fine. What am I missing?

```
package com.example.chrisjohnson.icitizenv2.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.chrisjohnson.icitizenv2.Card;
import com.example.chrisjohnson.icitizenv2.R;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by chrisjohnson on 7/7/15.
 */
public class TodayRecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TodayRecycleAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Card> data;
    private Context context;
    private static final int CASE_POLLS = 0;
    private static final int CASE_REPS = 1;
    private static final int CASE_NEWS = 2;
    private static final int CASE_BILLS = 3;
    private static final int CASE_PEERS = 4;

    public TodayRecycleAdapter(ArrayList<Card> data, Context context) {
        this.data = data;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
         TextView type;
         TextView title;
         TextView text;
         TextView office;
         TextView location;
         TextView time;
         TextView district;
         ImageView image;
         ImageView rep_office_icon;
         ImageView news_image;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            switch (getItemViewType()) {
                case 0:
                    type = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_type);
                    text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_text);
                    time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_poll_time);
                    image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_icon);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    type = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_type);
                    text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_text);
                    image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_icon);
                    news_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_news_image);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    type = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_type);
                    text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_rep_name);
                    image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_rep_image);
                    office = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_rep_office);
                    location = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_rep_location);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    type = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_type);
                    title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_title);
                    text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_text);
                    image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_bill_type_image);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    type = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_type);
                    text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_text);
                    time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_suggested);
                    image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_icon);
                    location = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_peer_location);
                    district = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_peer_district);
                    break;
            }
        }

        public ViewHolder(View itemView, TextView type, TextView title, TextView text,
                           TextView office, TextView location, TextView time, TextView district,
                           ImageView image, ImageView rep_office_icon, ImageView news_image) {
             super(itemView);
             this.type = type;
             this.title = title;
             this.text = text;
             this.office = office;
             this.location = location;
             this.time = time;
             this.district = district;
             this.image = image;
             this.rep_office_icon = rep_office_icon;
             this.news_image = news_image;
         }

    }

    @Override
    public TodayRecycleAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = null;
        switch (viewType) {
            case 0:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.polls_card_layout, null);

                break;
            case 1:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.news_card_layout, null);

                break;
            case 2:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.reps_card_layout, null);

                break;
            case 3:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.bills_card_layout, null);

                break;
            case 4:
                v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.peers_card_layout, null);

                break;
        }
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TodayRecycleAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
            case CASE_POLLS:
                viewHolder.type.setText(data.get(position).getType());
                viewHolder.text.setText(data.get(position).getText());
                viewHolder.time.setText(data.get(position).getTime());
                break;
            case CASE_NEWS:
                viewHolder.type.setText(data.get(position).getType());
                viewHolder.text.setText(data.get(position).getText());
                Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.news_photo).placeholder(R.drawable.news_photoholder).into(viewHolder.news_image);
                break;
            case CASE_REPS:
                viewHolder.type.setText(data.get(position).getType());
                viewHolder.text.setText(data.get(position).getText());
                viewHolder.office.setText(data.get(position).getOffice());
                viewHolder.location.setText(data.get(position).getLocation());
                /*if (position > 3) {
                    Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.rep_obama).placeholder(R.drawable.rep_obama).into(viewHolder.image);
                }*/
                break;
            case CASE_BILLS:
                viewHolder.type.setText(data.get(position).getType());
                viewHolder.title.setText(data.get(position).getTitle());
                viewHolder.text.setText(data.get(position).getText());
                break;
            case CASE_PEERS:
                viewHolder.type.setText(data.get(position).getType());
                viewHolder.text.setText(data.get(position).getText());
                viewHolder.time.setText(data.get(position).getTime());
                viewHolder.location.setText(data.get(position).getLocation());
                viewHolder.district.setText(data.get(position).getDistrict());
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (data.get(position).getType().equals("Bills")) {
            return CASE_BILLS;
        }
        else if (data.get(position).getType().equals("Reps")) {
            return CASE_REPS;
        }
        else if (data.get(position).getType().equals("Polls")) {
            return CASE_POLLS;
        }
        else if (data.get(position).getType().equals("Peers")) {
            return CASE_PEERS;
        }
        else {
            return CASE_NEWS;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure `data` is not empty ?

Comment: yes. because the list populates with the correct size, and I've checked it before it's sent into the adapter

Comment: is onBindViewHolder called ?

Comment: yes. It gets called right after onCreateViewHolder.

Comment: the code looks "good", try assigning different background colors to the different layouts, as a mean to debug

Comment: If the different layouts are getting displayed what's the point of changing their background color? Just curious

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82723/discussion-between-cj1098-and-blackbelt).

Comment: I probably misread your `white screens`

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, when I comment out all of the code in onBindViewHolder the layouts display. But without data. If I leave the code in, it's all white screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was in the constructor for the ViewHolder.

The switch statement I had with getItemViewType was never getting called. So now I'm finding the view's via the onCreateViewHolder method. There might be a better way to bind the views, but I haven't found it.